# HTTP Error 500.19 results -1 & 0

Tags: windows, iis, 500-error

I am trying to get my site to show up on the localhost. I have asp and asp.net installed in windows features and IIS does seem to work, however the problem is when I go to the site itself on the localhost I get this error

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

and then under it says

```
Config Source

   -1: 
    0:
```

Now I know the problem may be inside of the web.config file which is listed here...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What can I do to try to fix this? I've upload a screenshot.

[image]

[Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DflbX.jpg)

Comment: So is your site asp or asp.net?

Comment: Asp, I was able to fix the problem, it seems that the users wasn't added into the permissions as I thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by ACLs preventing the IIS process from accessing the config file. Make sure the account that the application pool is running under has read access to everything in the folder containing the website.